# transfer a number from one module to another

Tags: module, fortran, circular-dependency

I have 2 modules: A and B. A uses B. A reads in two numbers, then calls a subroutine in B that needs these numbers. How do I make these two numbers, read in in A, available in the subroutine in B without having them to add to the call to the subroutine?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities that I'm aware of:

1. Add them to the call.
2. Move the two numbers into a third module `C` and use these in both `A` and `B`.

You've said you don't want option 1 but, option 2 might be ok for you.

An (untested) example is

```
module A
 contains
    subroutine readNumbers()
        use C, only: a1, a2
        use B, only: theFinalRoutine
        !code to set a1 and a2
        call theFinalRoutine
    end subroutine readNumbers
 end module A

module B
 contains
    subroutine theFinalRoutine()
        use C, only: a1, a2
        !do some things with a1 and a2
    end subroutine theFinalRoutine
 end module B

module C
   real :: a1, a2
end module C

program test
   use A, only: readNumbers
   call readNumbers()
end program test
```

This isn't always a good idea, but it does help avoid circular dependencies in the case of data (rather than dependencies between routines).

Comment: Passing arguments other than through a routine's argument list is, at best, a dubious practice.  Widely practiced, I grant you, but dubious nonetheless.

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree, option 1 is how it should be done -- it's just OP explicitly asked for how to do it without adding to the call.

Comment: You could use a COMMON. :D